# Can I use AJAX to add SUBMIT button or hidden INPUT into PHP form?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, input

Hey guys I need my AJAX results to add fields to my FORM, or add a SUBMIT button to complete the form.

My AJAX results display in a DIV which is inside a standard HTML form (from a PHP file). When returned inside FORM tags, can AJAX results (as, say, hidden inputs) be included into the FORM POST??

I'm using a standard JavaScript (adapted from one posted for 'livesearch') to get AJAX results from AJAXresults.php which works fine - my AJAX results DO return OK, its just that my form doesn't work! The javascript is:

```
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length<4)
  {
  document.getElementById("suburbmatch").innerHTML="Type more than 4 letters...";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("suburbmatch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","AJAXresults.php?suburbtext="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

myphp.php includes the form like this: (note the DIV where AJAX results load, inside the FORM tags)

```
<form action="myphp.php" method="POST">

 <input type="text" name="addressline1">
 <input type="text" name="addressline2">
 <input type="text" name="suburb" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">

  <div id=suburbmatch></div>  // AJAX results display here

</form>
```

AJAXresults.php includes a script that queries a database then returns the results as a hidden input field, and a SUBMIT button:

```
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="suburbID" value="'.$row['ID'].'">');
echo ('<input type="submit" name="submit" value="');
echo ($row['suburb'].' '.$row['state'].' '.$row['zipcode']);
echo ('"><br>');
```

This code is in the WHILE loop, so 'suburbs' matching the text typed into the "suburb" text input on myphp.php load up as a button displaying the suburb/state/zipcode. When you click it, it should SUBMIT the whole form on myphp.php including the hidden INPUT from the AJAX results.

I could return the results as text and hyperlinking the data with $_GET, like: (a href=myphp.php?result=x) but then it will refresh the page and reset the other form values :P

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is YES!**

With **AJAX**, JavaScript can fetch **HTML form elements** (like a SUBMIT button or hidden INPUT), or even better, structured data (such as an object, like a JSON string) and then create form elements, and add them into a HTML / PHP form.

Just for the record, this is how I solved my issue:

First, I switched to jQuery to handle the AJAX function using `$.get()` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. This enabled me to handle errors amongst other advantages like better cross-browser compatibility.

And regarding adding the elements into the form, what I actually needed here was **user input** to choose the matching **address** *before* the form is sent (regardless of *how* the form is sent - later I would indeed use AJAX to perform this function too, using `$.post()`). Once the user selects the correct address from the list of matching addresses, a **hidden input** is then created (with the matching address ID number) and a **SUBMIT** button appears so the user can submit the form.

**More detail...**

The JavaScript function `showResult()` is fired `onKeyUp` when the user types in the **suburb** field, and returns a list of matching addresses:

```
// AJAXresults.php code in the WHILE loop:
echo '<li onclick="chooseThisAddress('.$row['ID'].')">'.$row['street'].', '.
$row['suburb'].' '.$row['state'].' '.$row['zipcode'].'</li>';

// which will output, in this example:
<li onclick="chooseThisAddress(64412)">1 Market St, Sydenham NSW 2044</li>
<li onclick="chooseThisAddress(64373)">1 Market St, Sydney NSW 2000</li>
```

User clicks the correct address, and a new function `chooseThisAddress()` is fired (with the address ID number passed to it), which simply hides the list of address matches, then creates the **hidden input** (e.g: `<input type="hidden" name="addressID" value="64412">`) and a **SUBMIT** button, both by using jQuery's `.append()` method (to append the new form elements to the form).

**So what was the original *problem*?**

Simply put, the way I was thinking of how the form would work, from the user's point of view, was making me think of having AJAX return a bunch of submit buttons. Since, I have found many ways of doing this differently, but this is how I ended up getting it done so that it was both functional and visually appealing.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you sumbmit this form via ajax only. This should solve your problem of refresh

Comment: So how will I get my "suburbID" (from the database query) if AJAX just posts the form data? I still need AJAX to return me a list of suburbs, so user can select one suburb. Then the form can be posted.

Comment: you can again get it via ajax, then can post your form. you can chain sequence of ajax statement one after another if required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning

```
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="suburbID" value="'.$row['ID'].'">');
```

in the WHILE loop. That means that you will have multiple html elements with same `name="suburbID"` and different values.
When you submit the form you will always get the value of the last one that will overwrite the value of others.

Comment: ahhh good point, thanks heaps for that! My form will still not post however :(

Comment: I've recreated this sitution quickly here: http://jsfiddle.net/TvFVY/ and the form posts normally. The only reasons I can think of is that, in your code, div `suburbmatch` is outside of the form so it can't submit.